# Does Java have an StringStream equivalent?

Tags: java

So I am trying to get back into Java after doing C++ for quite some time, I decided to practice by rewriting my C++ programs into Java. Now in my Min Max Program I have the following lines of code:

```
  //C++ Code Sample
  getline(cin,mystr);
  stringstream(mystr) >> value;

  max = value;
  min = value;

  stringstream stream(mystr);

      while(stream >> value)
      {
        if(value > max)
        {
          max = value;
        }
        else if(value < min)
        {
          min = value;
        }
      }
```

Now, getline is equivalent to using the Scanner class, but what of the StringStream? While searching I saw people mentioning InputStream, but that seems to be related to reading from a file, ex: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/inputstream_read.htm.

Thus, I was wondering if I can get similar functionality? I could of course also ask the user to specify how many inputs they wish to type in, and then just populate an array; but that seems awkward.

Update:

I created a quick work around that works as follows:

```
  String in = "";

            while(true)
            {

                in = input.nextLine();
                if(in.equalsIgnoreCase("DONE"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                value = Integer.parseInt(in);

                if(value > max)
                {
                    max = value;
                }
                else if(value < min)
                {
                    min = value;
                }
            }
```

Comment: "but that seems to be related to reading from a file" No, that can be any stream, including network, reading a byte array, and so on.

Comment: Noted, I as just looking at the example provided. Of course in the example provided it was a FileInputStream, is there an equivalent one from Scanner?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to parse a `String` using [Scanner(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29).  You can also use [java.lang.StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to construct strings in an efficient manner.

Comment: I see; thank you very much, I will look into. I did find a quick work around though.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to read a string of numbers from the input and then convert them to integers, you can use the following piece of code which does use Streams.

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the array of integers");

        String str = sc.nextLine();

        String[] strings = str.split(" ");

        List<Integer> ints = Stream.of(strings).
                               map(value -> Integer.valueOf(value)).
                               collect(Collectors.toList());
```